# Error using -itsoffset and enable=gt() with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I’m trying to add a short outro to the end of a video clip, which overlays starting at the final frame of that clip.

So far I can

- pad the clip displaying the final frame for 10 seconds (time for the animation to play)
- scale the videos to the correct matching dimensions
- overlay the animation to the clip

But I cannot start playing the animation at the right point.

Currently it works for arbitrary values, less than the initial duration of the clip, for example 5.6...

```
video="test-video.mp4"
output="test-video-outro.mp4"
duration='5.6'
ffmpeg -y -i $video -itsoffset $duration -i outro-frames/Outro.%05d.png \
-filter_complex "[0]tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=10[extended];[1][extended]scale2ref[scaled][ref];[ref][scaled]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable=gt(t\,$duration\)" \
$output
```

But when I use `ffprobe` to get the actual duration of the clip, and use that for the duration offset instead...

```
duration=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $video)
```

I know that the value is correct, `45.492133` for example, — but I get an error...

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7febc9853e00] moov atom not found
test-video-outro.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I’ve also tried to use `setpts` instead of `-itsoffset` but get the same error

```
ffmpeg -y -i $video -i outro-frames/Outro.%05d.png \
-filter_complex "[0]tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=10,setpts=PTS[extended];[1]setpts=PTS+$duration/TB[offset];[offset][extended]scale2ref[scaled][ref];[ref][scaled]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable=gt(t\,$duration\)" \
$output
```

It seems like the closer to the duration of the input video the more issues there are. Setting the duration to be a few seconds before the end the outro animation works but behaves strangely with some flickering.

I feel like I am close but now stuck, any advice appreciated.

Full output log

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -fno-stack-check' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test-video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41iso4
    creation_time   : 2020-04-26T13:32:15.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:15.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 587 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, Closed Captions, 453 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-26T13:32:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Vireo Eyes v2.5.3
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-26T13:32:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Vireo Ears v2.5.3
Input #1, image2, from 'outro-frames/Outro.%05d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:01.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, pal8(pc), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> tpad (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> setpts (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
-async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0.
[image2 @ 0x7f909303da00] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[libx264 @ 0x7f909301e200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f909301e200] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7f909301e200] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=22 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test-video-outro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41iso4
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-26T13:32:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Vireo Ears v2.5.3
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
./generate-youtube-video.sh: line 13: 28518 Segmentation fault: 11  ffmpeg -y -i $video -i outro-frames/Outro.%05d.png -filter_complex "[0]tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=10,setpts=PTS[extended];[1]setpts=PTS+$duration/TB[offset];[offset][extended]scale2ref[scaled][ref];[ref][scaled]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable=gt(t\,$duration\)" -async 1 $output
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1bb014800] moov atom not found
test-video-outro.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pad the video for this. overlay will extend the last frame of the main input and terminate when the longer input ends.

`ffmpeg -y -i $video -itsoffset $duration -i outro-frames/Outro.%05d.png \
-filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[scaled][ref];[ref][scaled]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable=gt(t\,$duration\)" \
$output`

(The missing moov atom error refers to a corrupt MP4/MOV file and is not related to the actual ffmpeg command or filters applied)

Comment: Thank you!

"overlay will extend the last frame of the main input and terminate when the longer input ends" — I don't think this is happening correctly though, because it does add the overlay at the right time, but it then stops halfway through the animation when the first input video finishes.

The reason I was adding some padding was because I also needed another 20 seconds after the PNG sequence animation finishes, it is a black screen which I need to continue with for a while longer.

Comment: Are you starting the overlay on the last frame of the main input or earlier?

Comment: Yes. It should start on last frame, overlay all the PNG sequence frames then extend the final, black frame for an arbitrary length of time (20 secs). This would be the ideal solution for me. In fact, with the code you posted if, instead of using an alpha PNG sequence, I use a Prores 4444 (with alpha) video then it trims at the end of the overlay video which is what I want. This isn’t quite ideal for me due to filesize but it gets the result I’ve been trying to achieve. Thanks for your advice — if you have a suggestion to make it work using the PNG sequence I’d love to know.

Comment: Sounds like your PNG sequence has varying pixel formats. Add `-reinit_filter 0` before `-i outro-frames/Outro.%05d.png`

Comment: Thank you so, so much that did it! This is exactly what I wanted, very much appreciated.